# I can't access datagrid from a custom event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've a simple script which looks at the clipboard. Once it's changed it throws an event that looks at the text contained and uses that text to populate a datagrid.

The event is working perfectly fine and retrieve the text as expected, but when I try to add a row to the datagrid nothing happens. Any suggestion?

```
    public void ClipBoardHasChanged(ClipboardMonitor m, ClipboardChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string clipBoardValue = (string)e.ClipboardChangedEventArgsT.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, true);
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = clipBoardValue;
    }
```

The Class of Clipboard

```
namespace MarketMatrixCorrelation
    {
        [DefaultEvent("ClipboardChanged")]
        public class ClipboardMonitor : Control
        {
            IntPtr nextClipboardViewer;

            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            protected static extern int SetClipboardViewer(int hWndNewViewer);

            [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern bool ChangeClipboardChain(IntPtr hWndRemove, IntPtr hWndNewNext);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

            public ClipboardMonitor()
            {
                this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                this.Visible = false;

                nextClipboardViewer = (IntPtr)SetClipboardViewer((int)this.Handle);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Clipboard contents changed.
            /// </summary>
            public delegate void ClipboardChanged(ClipboardMonitor s, ClipboardChangedEventArgs e);
            public event ClipboardChanged ClipboardChangedT = delegate { };


            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                ChangeClipboardChain(this.Handle, nextClipboardViewer);
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
            {
                // defined in winuser.h
                const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
                const int WM_CHANGECBCHAIN = 0x030D;

                switch (m.Msg)
                {
                    case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
                        SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);

                        OnClipboardChanged();
                        break;

                    case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
                        if (m.WParam == nextClipboardViewer)
                            nextClipboardViewer = m.LParam;
                        else
                            SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                        break;

                    default:
                        base.WndProc(ref m);
                        break;
                }
            }

            //Catch when something is posted on the clipboard
            private void OnClipboardChanged()
            {
                try
                {
                    ClipboardChangedEventArgs iData = new ClipboardChangedEventArgs();
                    iData.ClipboardChangedEventArgsT = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                    if (iData.ClipboardChangedEventArgsT.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
                    {
                        ClipboardChangedT(this, iData);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public class ClipboardChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            private IDataObject DataObject;

            public IDataObject ClipboardChangedEventArgsT
            {
                set
                {
                    DataObject = value;
                }
                get
                {
                    return this.DataObject;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes correct. This is just to show what I'm after. The only problem is nothing happens! Nothing is added to the datagridview.

Comment: I apologize i deleted my comment.. try my answer, you're in winform?

Comment: No worries. Yes I'm in winform. My event is in a separate class, but it seems is working correcly (ie. if I copy to the clipboard a string like "aaaa" the variable clipBoardValue reflects corretly "aaaa").

Answer (score 0):

Just place the `ClipBoardMonitor` in your `Form` and paste this in `Form Load Event`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.clipboardMonitor1.ClipboardChangedT += (o, ex) =>
    {
        string clipBoardValue = (string)ex.ClipboardChangedEventArgsT.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, true);
        object[] row = { clipBoardValue };
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi spajce, thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: There is no error. It is processed correctly but nothing appears in the datagrid.

Comment: so if you're trying adding rows with from the value in `clipBoard`. i tested the above code.. but everythings fine

Comment: It works for me as well by using a button, but not under the clipboard event. I really don't understand it. Can it be related to the event (ie. the event itself avoid to communicate with the datagrid?). Happy to share the entire code if this can be helpful.

Comment: mhmm thats strange.. try to debug it or put a breakpoint in the `ClipBoardHasChanged event`

Comment: No errors are thrown. clipBoardValue returns exactly what it is supposed to return, but nothing gets added to the datagrid!

Comment: can you also share your clipboard class?

Comment: just tested and everything is work fine.. are your really sure the event was called? or you have already place the control `ClipMonitor` in your form?

Comment: Can you please send across your code? I'll give you my email: denegri.antonio@gmail.com